# How to get the Monthly Cost of aws ec2 instance using CLI tools

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to get the Details of every instance available and their respective monthly costs, Usage details. Is there any  cli command that can fetch the const details and export to csv file. How to achieve this through CLI. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is no any single CLI command that you will run and get the monthly pricing. you will have to integrate the AWS Price List API to get the pricing.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-price-list-api/

This is also a good tool available to get the costs for the EC2 instances.

https://github.com/colinbjohnson/aws-missing-tools/blob/master/_deprecated/ec2-cost-calculate/ec2-cost-calculate.sh

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The first link gives the price details of AWS services right not my instance or the cost estimate of my usage. am I right?

Comment: i tried the second link in your answer but getting Required option '-O, --aws-access-key KEY' missing (-h for usage)   ---this error. I have exported the keys but still the same error. any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Go into your AWS account billing settings and enabled [detailed billing reports](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/detailed-billing-reports.html). Once you've followed the instructions on that page you will have detailed billing reports that AWS is delivering to an S3 bucket in your account. There will be several different reports delivered to that S3 bucket, all in CSV format.

Comment: I am trying to get it from command line because if i go with S3 then again i have to pay for S3 service. the cost increases..

Comment: The cost of storing those files on S3 is going to be a few pennies.

Comment: @ScottStensland that report has obviously been deprecated since I posted this answer 3 years ago. I don't work for Amazon. If you have a complaint about the Amazon billing reports I suggest you file that complaint on their site, not here.